# Проблема сжатия файлов в ресурсах при компиляции

Tags: java, intellij-idea, компиляция, io, resources

Всем привет!
Разрабатывая проект, заметил такой баг, что `idea`, при компиляции проекта в `.jar`, искажает файл в ресурсах с расширением `.schem`.
По логике программы, у меня этот файл копируется из папки ресурсов проекта во внешнюю и после уже используется, но его содержимое искажается.
Метод распаковки

```
protected File createFileIfNotExist(){
        if(!file.exists()){
            try {
                file.getParentFile().mkdirs();
                Files.copy(getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(sourcePath + file.getName()), file.toPath());
                return file;
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                logger.warning("Не удалось создать " + file.getName());
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

исходный, не битый файл - https://disk.yandex.ru/d/dfDGXnFM93Xj8Q

битый, после компиляции - https://disk.yandex.ru/d/XQjplytsqKKBiA

Заранее спасибо!